# Prove that a line is a bisector of the angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In a parallelogram $ABCD$ points $M$ and $N$ were chosen on the sides $AB$ and $BC$ respectively. $AM = NC$. The point $Q$ is the intersection point of the line segments $AN$ and $CM$. How can I prove that $DQ$ is the bisector of the angle $D$?[image]

Comment: Are you interested in a proof using vectors?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let's call $P$ the intersection between the lines through $AN$ and $DC$.

So, $\Delta QCP$ and $\Delta MQA$ are similars, and then

$$\frac{QP}{AQ}=\frac{PC}{AM}\quad (1)$$

we also have $\Delta NPC$ and $\Delta ABN$ are similars, then

$$\frac{PC}{AB}=\frac{NC}{BN}\to\frac{PC}{AB}=\frac{AM}{BN}\to \frac{PC}{AM}=\frac{AB}{BN}\quad (2)$$

but $\Delta ABN$ and $\Delta ADP$ are also similars, then

$$\frac{AB}{PD}=\frac{BN}{AD}\to \frac{AB}{BN}=\frac{PD}{AD}\quad (3)$$

putting together $(1), (2), (3)$ we get:

$$\frac{QP}{AQ}=\frac{PD}{AD}$$

and by bissector theorem we get that $QD$ is the bissector of the angle $\angle D$ in the triangle $\Delta ADP$.

Comment: @idliketodothis: Is it clear?